# How to merge a CSProj file in TFS, when auto merge fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge, visual-studio-2013

Another Developer and I both added a new file to the same project in TFS Online (through VS 2013).  (different names) He checked in his changes.  I did a get latest.  Instead of Merging, it gave me this error:

```
Conflict [project file path].csproj - Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit
```

There was no change on my side.  The project file was not updated.  The new file from his side did not get copied on to my file system.

We have not configured any merging rules in TFS online, it is all default settings.

Right clicking on the project in Solution Explorer does NOT bring up a Merge Option.  From Source Control Explorer, I can right click on the CSProj file, go to Merge, but that brings up a window about finding what to merge it with, and only lets you select from the same path, not selecting a version.  It complains that it is not a branch of it self, and cannot be merged.

Here is the conflicting lines in the CSProj versions:

Checked In CS Project, Line 1390:

```
<Content Include="TextFile2.txt" />
```

My CS Project, Line 1390:

```
<Content Include="TextFile1.txt" />
```

Comment: I don't understand; a get latest will require you to merge, it will not cancel because there are remote changes.

Comment: @Edward: I just updated with additional information, showing that auto-merge does not work in this circumstance

Comment: So, When the automerge fails, in this case, how can I trigger a manual one?

Comment: You're confusing merge of branches with automerge on get latest. There are two entirely different operations. Regarding the error, ultimately you need to bring the conflict resolution window and resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing Get Latest from Visual Studio does trigger the merge. CSPROJ is an XML file, thus should be merged automatically upon get latest by default, unless there are [**conflicts**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181432.aspx) in which Visual Studio will open the conflict resolution dialog so you can review your edits against theirs.

You can get latest from the `Source Control Explorer`, right click on the solution root folder and click `Get Latest Version`. If there are conflicts, the `Resolve Conflicts` dialog should pop up. If the file was merged automatically, you should see it on the [**Diff**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385990.aspx) dialog (right click the file and click `Compare`).

If the `Resolve Conflicts` windows does not appear:

1. Open the `Pending Changes` tab.
2. In case you have more than one workspace, make sure you've selected the correct one.
3. Click the `Actions` menu -> `Resolve Conflicts`

Comment: "Conflict [path to project file].csproj - Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit" another developer an I both added a file (different names) to the project. He checked in.  I did a get latest.  It did not merge, it gave me that error.  It also did not get the file they checked in either.

Comment: I have added additional information to the top showing that Get Latest does not Auto Merge (for CSProj files at least, and on our default system).  Also, Resolve conflict doesn't show up from the right click of the folder or file in source control explorer.

Comment: In response to: "If there are conflicts, the Resolve Conflict dialog should pop up" --> That did not occur.  I only got the error line I had by reading through the source control output, which had not more details than What I showed above.

Comment: 1. Open the pending changes tab. 2. In case you have more than one workspace, make sure you've selected the correct one. 3. Click the Actions menu -> Resolve Conflicts.

Comment: Awesome!  That resolved it.  It also obtained the additional file when merging the csproj file.  --> Can you edit your answer to include this information?  Thanks.